# Duplicate tweets on twitter widget when tabbing and widget updates

Tags: twitter

I have multiple embedded timelines on a website I am developing. The HTML for these timelines are auto-generated by TweetDeck.

Scenario:
1. A user switches to a different tab in the browser.
2. The timeline widget receives updates with multiple new tweets.
3. When the user re-activates the tab, the embedded timelines get flooded with duplicate tweets.

I have tried to change multiple parameter settings for the embedded-timeline class, but have not been able to fix this issue.

Does anybody know what might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The twitter devs will fix the issue in the next deploy. They are aiming for a release on 08.09.2015.
As I was finding the same issue, I posted it to the twitter community forum (apologize for the copy/paste). 
https://twittercommunity.com/t/duplicate-tweets-on-twitter-widget-when-tabbing-and-widget-updates/51493

Comment: @Heyyou I would not say this is a link-only answer, as this seems to be a confirmed bug, and the answerer points to the ticket. cf. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303976/4132844